# Segmentation Fault in Python uWSGI application

Tags: python, numpy, segmentation-fault, uwsgi, blas

I am fairly new to using uwsgi with python scripts, so hopefully this is a naive mistake.

I have two different web applications that interact with separate but related python libraries, lets call them lib1.py and lib2.py

If I use these libraries from the command line, I get no errors.

I have created two python files, app1.py and app2.py that are each attached to different uwsgi sockets. The basic framework of these files is:

```
import lib1.py

#load objects into memory
MyObject = lib1.MyClass(init_params)

application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'

    output = MyObject.processRequest()

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/html'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]

    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

Same for app2.py importing lib2...

App1 works great and I had no problem getting it set up. It loads dozens of large (100000+ rows, ~100 columns) numpy arrays when MyObject is initialized and keeps them in memory for the application function to calculate on when it receives requests from the web server.

App2 has not yet worked... lib2.py imports lib1.py as it needs to do similar calculations on a large numpy array as part of its job. The weird thing is that its one of the lib1.py functions that throws the SEGFAULT. At first, I thought maybe this was a symptom of some weird double-importing going on, which is why I separated the uwsgi into two separate sockets and apps as described above when I first saw this happening. The weirder thing is that lib2 uses only 1 large numpy array, and it is smaller than the largest of the lib1 numpy arrays. By placing a number of `print` statements into my code and looking at the logs, I was able to find the exact line where the segfault is happening:

```
inner_product_array = np.dot(self.coordinates, vector.T)
```

self.coordinates is a 2d MxN array, and vector.T is an Nx1 column vector. The SEGFAULT goes away, if I limit the self.coordinates array like so: `self.coordinates[:500,:]`

But the SEGFAULT happens whenever the slice gets much bigger than 500, which is nowhere near the 150000 I need. Again, this calculation causes no problem in lib1, when self.coordinates can get up to 500000 x 200

I feel like I have followed through as much as possible in terms of making sure that no modules/libraries were being double imported. Other numpy functions behave fine, and, again, lib2 works perfectly fine with large arrays when used from the command line.

The only other weird symptom to mention is that, before, when I had a single app.py file that handled all my uwsgi python code and handled requests for different apps using the PATH_INFO environment variable (including others besides these two), all the apps worked fine together until I added lib2. Once lib2 was added, lib1 broke and started giving SEGFAULTS as well. The other apps (which have no dependencies on lib1 or lib2) were fine.

Here is the error from the log:

```
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 33866, cores: 1)
!!! uWSGI process 33866 got Segmentation Fault !!!
*** backtrace of 33866 ***
0   uwsgi                               0x00000001062f9420 uwsgi_backtrace + 48
1   uwsgi                               0x00000001062f9963 uwsgi_segfault + 51
2   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fff9190ef1a _sigtramp + 26
3   multiarray.so                       0x0000000106fd4efe array_dealloc + 158
4   libBLAS.dylib                       0x00007fff908911ff rowMajorNoTranspose + 689
5   libBLAS.dylib                       0x00007fff9088f2c9 cblas_dgemv + 783
6   _dotblas.so                         0x00000001072e0129 dotblas_matrixproduct + 5513
7   libpython2.7.dylib                  0x00000001067d27c9 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 14387
8   libpython2.7.dylib                  0x00000001067ced62 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1413
9   libpython2.7.dylib                  0x00000001067d557d _PyEval_SliceIndex + 757
10  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x00000001067d23e3 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13389
11  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x00000001067ced62 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1413
12  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x00000001067d557d _PyEval_SliceIndex + 757
13  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x00000001067d23e3 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13389
14  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x00000001067ced62 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1413
15  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x00000001067d557d _PyEval_SliceIndex + 757
16  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x00000001067d23e3 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13389
17  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x00000001067ced62 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1413
18  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x00000001067d557d _PyEval_SliceIndex + 757
19  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x00000001067d23e3 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13389
20  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x00000001067ced62 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1413
21  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x000000010677330a PyFunction_SetClosure + 826
22  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x00000001067552ac PyObject_Call + 99
23  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x00000001067d4d6b PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 93
24  uwsgi                               0x0000000106314097 python_call + 23
25  uwsgi                               0x000000010631620f uwsgi_request_wsgi + 879
26  uwsgi                               0x00000001062ab530 wsgi_req_recv + 288
27  uwsgi                               0x00000001062f7205 simple_loop_run + 229
28  uwsgi                               0x00000001062fe577 uwsgi_ignition + 439
29  uwsgi                               0x00000001062fe363 uwsgi_worker_run + 835
30  uwsgi                               0x00000001062fbe7a uwsgi_run + 442
31  uwsgi                               0x00000001062f9b0e main + 14
32  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff854425c9 start + 1
*** end of backtrace ***
```

And here is the xml config for uwsgi I am using for app2:

```
<uwsgi>
    <socket>127.0.0.1:3033</socket>
    <chdir>/abs/path/to/site_folder/wsgi</chdir>
    <wsgi-file>/abs/path/to/site_folder/wsgi/app2.py</wsgi-file>
    <logto>/abs/path/to/logdir/app2.log</logto>
    <pidfile>app2.pid</pidfile>
    <enable-threads></enable-threads>
    <daemonize2></daemonize2>
</uwsgi>
```

**UPDATE**

I created an identical set-up on an Amazon Linux EC-2 server and everything worked without error. The local machine on which I am having the problem is OSX. I am still confused why this is happening only when in the uWSGI framework, and would like to be able to develop and test locally, but it seems it's likely more an installation issue (OpenBLAS?) than anything else. Any ideas why uWSGI would be triggering this misbehavior on identical data and in an identical function call as both an errorless command-line script and a separate errorless uWSGI application?